# Quartz.Net Schedular IsStarted property remains true always after UnScheduleJobs, Shutdown, PauseAll, DeleteJobs and GetCurrentlyExecutingJob etc

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I am using `Quartz.Net` for scheduling the job from code. All working fine except the status.

I want to show the current status of job as Running and Stopped.

I am getting the `IsStarted` always `true` after the schedule started once.

How can I get the value of `IsStarted` `false` while stop the schedule?

I have tried all the methods `UnScheduleJobs`, `Shutdown`, `PauseAll`, `DeleteJobs` and `GetCurrentlyExecutingJob`. But failed to get result.

Here is my code:

```
public static class BillScheduleExtension
{
    public static List<JobKey> jobKeys = new List<JobKey>();
    public static List<TriggerKey> triggerKeys = new List<TriggerKey>();
    public static ISchedulerFactory schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
    public static IScheduler scheduler = schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();

    public static bool SchdularStarted()
    {
        return scheduler.IsStarted;
    }
    public static void StopSchduleProcess()
    {
        if (triggerKeys.Count > 0)
        {
            //scheduler.DeleteJobs(jobKeys);
            //scheduler.Shutdown();
            scheduler.UnscheduleJobs(triggerKeys);
            scheduler.PauseAll();
            //scheduler.IsStarted = false;
            //foreach (var jbkey in jobKeys)
            //{
            //    scheduler.Interrupt(jbkey);
            //}
        }
    }
    public static void StartSchduleProcess(Session ss)
    {
        XPQuery<BillSchedule> _schedule = new XPQuery<BillSchedule>(ss);
        try
        {
            var count = 0;
            foreach (BillSchedule bs in _schedule)
            {
                JobDataMap jm = new JobDataMap();
                jm.Put("jobsession", ss);
                IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<BillJob>()
                .WithIdentity("BillJob" + count.ToString(), null)
                .SetJobData(jm)
                .Build();
                ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithIdentity("Billtrigger" + count.ToString(), null)
                .WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInMinutes(bs.Day))
                .Build();
                triggerKeys.Add(trigger.Key);
                scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
                count++;
            }
            scheduler.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the API Documentation](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/apidoc/2.0/html/).

`IScheduler.IsStarted` property

> This only reflects whether Start() has ever been called on this Scheduler, so it will return true even if the IScheduler is currently in standby mode or has been since shutdown.

Maybe you should check property `IsShutdown` and `InStandbyMode`.

Comment: The IsShutdown is not working But InStandbyMode is working correctly. Thanks @silverfox